# Register HoverProvider with Xtend

Tags: xtext, xtend

I try to implement a custom HoverProvider according to this tutorial: [enter link description here](https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/hover-support-in-xtext-2-0-tutorial/)

However, I'm stuck translating to Java code of `MyDSLUiModule`to Xtend.
The register-method should read like this:

```
 def Class<? extends IEObjectDocumentationProvider> bindIEObjectDocumentationProviderr() {
    return MyDSLHoverProvider.class
}
```

However, this doesn't compile since `MyDSLHoverProvider` only `implements` the `IEObjectDocumentationProvider` but not `extend` this class (`MyDSLHoverProvider` is the same as in the tutorial).

Therefore this error is thrown:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<? extends Class> to Class<? extends IEObjectDocumentationProvider>`

How can I get around this error?

Btw: If I test my DSL in an Eclipse instance, I get a wierd NPE:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui 2 0 2016-09-16 16:42:34.203
>   !MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:373)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$4(SetupUIPlugin.java:344)
>       at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:241)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

I have no clue where this exception comes from.

The class MyDSLHoverProvider looks like this:

```
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
import org.eclipse.xtext.documentation.IEObjectDocumentationProvider

class MyDSLHoverProvider implements IEObjectDocumentationProvider {

    override getDocumentation(EObject o) {
        println("Hover: " + o)
        if (o instanceof MyFieldElements) {
            return "This is a nice Greeting with nice <b>markup</b> in the <i>documentation</i>";
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:
I found a way to display the tooltips, but it seems strange.
A tooltip is shown for this rule:

```
name = ID
```

but if I rename it to

```
myField = ID
```

the tooltip is not triggered.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct Xtend syntax is

```
def Class<? extends IEObjectDocumentationProvider> bindIEObjectDocumentationProviderr() {
    return MyDSLHoverProvider
}
```

or

```
def Class<? extends IEObjectDocumentationProvider> bindIEObjectDocumentationProviderr() {
    MyDSLHoverProvider
}
```

`MyDSLHoverProvider.class`is the same as `MyDslHoverProvider.class.getClass()` in Java

Comment: Ah, yes, the compile error is gone! :-) However, the tooltip is still not being shown. The `bindIEObjectDocumentationProviderr` method is definitly called, but the method in `MyDSLHoverProvider`is never being fired. I updated my post to give the complete code of `MyDSLHoverProvider` and the trace of a wierd NPE at Eclipse startup.

Comment: can you give more context: grammar, example model, your impl and how you test it

Comment: I updated my starting post. I had to rename my fields to `name` to get the tooltips shown. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes see ilocationinfileprovider and it's use in the hover